# Android: How to implement Rotatable Semi-circular?

Tags: rotation, android, gesture

[image]

I want to rotate the semi-circular as the upper picture(maybe the view's backgroud). **How to implement it?**

It should be rotated by the gesture . It maybe like the rotatable circular, but only display the half of the one. I had implemented the rotatable circular using the matrix , but I have no idea about the semi-circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved the problem, like these:

```
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h/2);
canvas.clipRect(rect);
canvas.save();
```